# How to stop reformatting of the class/file after refactoring

Tags: php, phpstorm

Once I move a class to a new namespace or to another existing namespace,after moving it reformats the file.
What I want move the class, but don't format the file

Answer (score 0):

If the class is in it's own separate file, try refactor->move (`F6`) on the file in the project explorer to the new location, that should take care of the namespace as well if it conforms to the standard set in your composer.json file (if it is a composer project)

Comment: I'm able to move/refactor the namespace. But after move file is being formatted. That should not happen. See the question again

Comment: settings > editor > general > smart keys > and the last option "Reformat on paste" try setting that to none

Comment: This is not solving my problem. It's still formatting